# Can you tell me which font is this?

Tags: typography, font-identification

**[image]
Can anyone tell me which font is this ??

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - *Please* look through **[tour]** to get a sense of our community – who we are and what we’re about. *Then* look over **[ask]** and **[answer]** a question to see what makes a good query here, *and* how best to frame it. We have some specific requirements for font identification questions, please take a look and [edit] your question to meet those guidelines - thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than the spurs/flat caps on the top and bottom....

Not an *exact* match, but [Letterhead Fonts Western Rose](https://www.letterheadfonts.com/fonts/westernrose) is pretty close.

[image]

> [image]

The flat edges were, most likely, created manually to emphasize the overall shape. Or in all probability.... the designer of Western Rose used something similar as inspiration.

Comment: That will do. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It looks hand drawn, and so it's probably not an actual font you can download. Not everything that has been printed is a font.

Please also note that the lettering in the example is from a poster for the 1904 St Louis Olympic Games, making it highly unlikely that it is available for download, unless someone has specifically recreated the font.

You can find similar styled fonts using the term "Art Nouveau" to search with. For example [here](https://www.fontspring.com/tag/art-nouveau). I am not affiliated with this website.